# Parsear data en React

Tags: reactjs

Al hacer un llamado a un endpoint de la api para insertar data(metodo post), tendria que pasarle un objeto como este

```
{
    workCenterId: "",
    userId: "",
    workOrderId: "",
    sequences: [
        {
            id: "",
            cantidadIngresada: "",
        }
    ]
}
```

Primero hago un chequeo de que fila esta chequeada(para mandar solo la data de esao esas filas) y luego recorro esa fila y devuelvo un nuevo arreglo(aca esta el error porque tendria que devolver un objeto y no un arreglo, y se que con map se devuelve un nuevo arreglo). De esta manera la respuesta del back es un status code 400 de bad request

```
const filasSeleccionadas = infoGrilla.filter((dCheck) => {
      return dCheck.checked;
    });
    console.log(filasSeleccionadas);


    const dataFilas = filasSeleccionadas.map((data) => {
      const infoEndpoint = {
        workOrderId: "",
        workCenterId: "",
        userId: "",
        sequences: [
          {
            id: "",
            cantidadIngresada: "",
          },
        ],
      };
      return infoEndpoint;
    });
```

Como tendria que hacer para resolver este problema?
Gracias

Comment: map() no te devuelve un arreglo, lo que hace es hacer una copia de un arreglo, asi que probablemente no tengas un objeto como dices, si no mas bien un arreglo, de otra forma map no te funcionaria, ya que solo es para arreglos.

Comment: claro. ahora estoy teniendo un arreglo y no un objeto como necesito para mandarlo al back

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu Api aparentemente solo acepta enviar un elemento a la vez con la firma que mencionas, si tenes una grilla donde podes seleccionar varios elementos y por cada elemento seleccionada lo transformas a la forma que le tenes que enviar a la API si o si vas a tener que llamar tantas veces tu API como elementos hayas seleccionado. Entonces tu aproach no esta mal solo que luego de aplicar el map en el array de elementos filtrados anteriormente, vas a tener un array ya con los elementos adaptados a la forma que te pide tu api y vas a tener que recorrerlos para llamar a la api por cada elemento.
Saludos!